# Slow performing postgresql commit statements

Tags: django, postgresql, gunicorn, gevent

In a Django web app with a postgresql backend (and nginx reverse proxy with gunicorn application server), I'm seeing dozens of `COMMIT` messages in postgresql's slow log. Behold:

```
2020-02-01 17:56:16.335 UTC [19424] ubuntu@app LOG LOG:  duration: 175.630 ms  statement: COMMIT
2020-02-01 17:56:21.355 UTC [19435] ubuntu@app LOG LOG:  duration: 107.735 ms  statement: COMMIT
2020-02-01 17:57:22.592 UTC [19419] ubuntu@app LOG LOG:  duration: 235.313 ms  statement: COMMIT
2020-02-01 17:57:30.685 UTC [19419] ubuntu@app LOG LOG:  duration: 249.875 ms  statement: COMMIT
2020-02-01 17:57:30.688 UTC [19424] ubuntu@app LOG LOG:  duration: 99.049 ms  statement: COMMIT
2020-02-01 17:57:30.688 UTC [19435] ubuntu@app LOG LOG:  duration: 115.772 ms  statement: COMMIT
2020-02-01 17:57:30.688 UTC [19554] ubuntu@app LOG LOG:  duration: 248.656 ms  statement: COMMIT
2020-02-01 17:58:03.266 UTC [19435] ubuntu@app LOG LOG:  duration: 780.232 ms  statement: COMMIT
2020-02-01 17:58:03.270 UTC [19424] ubuntu@app LOG LOG:  duration: 622.424 ms  statement: COMMIT
2020-02-01 17:58:07.579 UTC [19435] ubuntu@app LOG LOG:  duration: 75.658 ms  statement: COMMIT
```

The DB in question was just migrated from one dedicated server to another a day ago. In its previously environment, `COMMIT` *never* showed up in `slow log`. In the new environment, I made some changes:

1) I set `checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7` (down from `checkpoint_completion_target = 0.8` previously)

2) I switched to `gevent` workers in gunicorn (previously used `sync` workers). This also entailed I add the following to postgresql (allowing us to use `psycopg2` asynchronously with `gevent` - [source](https://pypi.org/project/psycogreen/)):

```
from psycogreen.gevent import patch_psycopg

def post_fork(server, worker):
  from gevent import monkey

  patch_psycopg()
  worker.log.info("Made PostgreSQL Green!")
  monkey.patch_all()
```

3) Increased `max_connections` to `400` (from `300` previously)

4) Increased `shared_buffers` to `8GB` (from `6GB` previously)

And also a few other changes where I *increased* the thresholds (which ought to be a good thing).

Can an expert suggest whether the changes I've made above might have led to all the COMMIT statements littering my `slow log`? If not, any other guesses?

And most importantly, what are some mitigation steps I can take to ameliorate this situation?

---

`vmstat 1` yields:

```
ubuntu@main-app:~$ vmstat 1
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
16  0      0 10031160 263796 11650344    0    0     2    20    5    4 13  1 86  0  0
 2  0      0 10030184 263796 11650308    0    0     0  1832 8598 9433 20  1 78  0  0
 4  1      0 10028432 263796 11650416    0    0    40   436 7229 7887 20  1 79  0  0
 6  0      0 10027076 263796 11650456    0    0     0   764 7836 8833 17  1 81  0  0
 4  0      0 10025904 263796 11650464    0    0     0   588 7947 9754 22  1 76  0  0
 4  0      0 10025988 263796 11650512    0    0     0   652 9727 12033 30  2 68  0  0
 7  0      0 10025572 263796 11650532    0    0     0   816 8296 9984 25  1 73  0  0
 2  1      0 10025680 263796 11650596    0    0     0  1128 8794 11003 23  1 75  0  0
 0  0      0 10025552 263796 11650588    0    0     0   288 7153 8091 20  1 79  0  0
 6  0      0 10025096 263796 11650612    0    0     0   412 9423 12016 25  2 73  0  0
 1  0      0 10025056 263796 11650640    0    0     0   240 9227 11442 32  2 66  0  0
 6  0      0 10025056 263796 11650800    0    0    32  1036 8762 10418 25  2 73  0  0
 2  0      0 10025116 263796 11650828    0    0     0   352 8730 10924 23  2 75  0  0
 6  0      0 10024992 263796 11650940    0    0     0   592 7920 9399 14  1 85  0  0
 3  0      0 10024288 263796 11650952    0    0     0   380 8380 9662 23  1 75  0  0
 4  0      0 10024536 263796 11650896    0    0     0   680 9193 10819 22  1 76  0  0
 1  0      0 10024720 263796 11650776    0    0     0   588 9655 10757 24  2 74  0  0
 5  0      0 10024820 263796 11650700    0    0     0    48 10237 13216 28  2 70  0  0
 1  0      0 10023660 263796 11650716    0    0     0   396 9291 11251 34  2 64  0  0
 6  0      0 10024564 263796 11650744    0    0     0   720 8557 10500 22  1 76  0  0
```

Comment: What was the storage hardware on each server?  Slow commit is usually slow fdatasync.

Comment: @jjanes: thanks for clarifying. The new one is a Digital Ocean Block Store volume (SSD - 5K IOPS, 200MB/s throughput). The old one was an AWS Elastic block store volume (SSD - 16K IOPS, 250 MB/s throughput). But do note that my writes don't normally exceed 400 kB/s. Is there anything I can do to improve fdatasync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two likely explanations for slow commits:

1. Overloaded storage. This can be caused by

   - The high I/O volume.
   - Lots of small transactions, where the WAL sync requests are just too many.
2. `WITH HOLD` cursors on larger queries.

On Linux, check the `%iowait` column in `vmstat 1` to see if the I/O subsystem is overloaded.

About your measures:

- Increasing `max_connections` or decreasing `checkpoint_completion_target` will have an adverse effect, if anything.
- Increasing `shared_buffers` will help if the problem is the amount of read I/O.
- If the problem are the many sync requests, and you can afford to lose a few committed transactions in the event of a crash, set `synchronous_commit = off`.

  If that is not an option, you can play with `commit_delay` to get the I/O load down.

I have never heard of "gevent workers", so I cannot say anything about them.

Comment: Just to add more data (in case it tweaks your answer). The new environment I've migrated to is a Digital Ocean Block Store volume (SSD - 5K IOPS, 200MB/s throughput). The old one was an AWS Elastic block store volume (SSD - 16K IOPS, 250 MB/s throughput). But do note that my writes don't normally exceed 400 kB/s.

Comment: Moreover, added `vmstat 1` output at the end of the question

Comment: If that `vmstat` output covers the time when you observe the long commits, then I/O can be pretty much ruled out as an explanation. That would leave the `WITH HOLD` cursors, but that should not suddenly surface on a new system.

Comment: Well the app is a social networking app - not a mission-critical financial/banking app - so I suppose setting `synchronous_commit=off`makes sense. I'll try that out and get back to you.

Comment: But that will only help if you are I/O bound due to many transactions.

Comment: Well, after making this change, it does seem the query time of `Postgres commit` statements has gone down significantly (according to new relic).

Comment: Nice. Then my guess is that the `vmstat` sample is from a time where the problem does *not* occur.

Comment: Yep, seems like it. I did take that output at a high traffic point in time (when commit statements were showing up in my slow log every now and then), however it's possible I might have missed it.