# PostgreSQL slow COMMITs

Tags: postgresql, performance, kubernetes

I see lots of slow COMMITs in my logs :

```
2023-10-06 14:35:47 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[16591] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1049.941 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTdiSzE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTdiWAAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:35:47 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[24320] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1049.209 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTdjzzE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTdj1QAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:35:47 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[27681] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1048.986 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTdjNDE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTdjOgAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:35:47 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[18060] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1188.703 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTdiTTE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTdiVwAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:35:43 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[28640] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1033.370 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTdgsjE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTdhHwAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:30:46 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[16339] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1478.801 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTba9zE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTba/wAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:30:45 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[27878] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1233.219 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTba1jE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTba3QAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:30:43 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[27878] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1012.639 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbatjE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbavAAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:30:31 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[28640] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1228.278 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbYMjE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbYOgAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:30:30 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[16339] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1268.856 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbYFDE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbYGwAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:30:27 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[16339] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 2105.008 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbXyzE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbX0QAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:30:27 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[28640] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 2127.526 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbXtDE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbXwAAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:30:22 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[16339] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1535.906 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbWxTE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbWzQAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:30:21 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[28640] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1242.736 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbWpzE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbWrgAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:30:20 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[28640] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1455.468 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbWNjE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbWPAAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:30:19 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[16339] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1986.581 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbWHzE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTbWJgAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:14:58 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[28640] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1637.472 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTS3MzE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTS3PgAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:14:53 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[28640] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1040.691 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTSzWTE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTSzYAAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:13:34 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[28640] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1178.765 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTRwsjE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTRwtQAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:10:11 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[16270] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1156.853 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTO+ETE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTO+FwAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:10:03 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[18060] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1835.203 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTN3HDE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTN3KgAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:10:03 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[19612] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1835.187 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTN3GDE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTN3LgAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:10:02 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[26583] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1725.870 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTN3GjE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTN3LQAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:09:55 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[18060] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1594.778 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTNxlTE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTNxnAAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:09:53 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[18060] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1023.697 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTNtPTE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTNtQwAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:09:53 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[24320] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1023.716 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTNsXDE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTNsagAAAAQAAAAA'
2023-10-06 14:09:53 CEST Tx[0] cmd[COMMIT PREPARED] PID[28640] DB[db_XX] LOG: duration: 1023.706 ms execute <unnamed>: COMMIT PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTNsWzE=_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//ZGKVXjMhkrRlCESsBTNsZwAAAAQAAAAA'
```

Most of them are related to transactions doing ONLY SELECT queries.

I checked memory, disk/IO, everything is fine.
When I run pgbench I have good transaction/second rates.

How to debug what's being slow on such COMMITs ?

How to tune that ?

This is my config :

- PostgreSQL 12.6, Alpine based image
- 12g memory, 1 to 8 cores
- 8g shared_buffers
- synchronous_commit = 'off'

Comment: Why not use the latest version like 15 or 16

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slow performing postgresql commit statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60020180/slow-performing-postgresql-commit-statements)

Comment: Why do you use PREPARED transactions? These are slow by design because they have to more (remote) work. It's also a rather unusual combination with synchronous_commit = 'off'. One one hand you say that transactions are extremely important, even over different applications, and on the other had you say that it is allow to loose a transaction. I would not expect this combination.

Comment: Interesting point, I suppose this is the default with JTA transactions.
Our JEE application is "multi-tenant", but rarly (or never) needs distributated transactions on multiple databases.
Is the performance gain bewteen PREPARED and normal transactions so significant ?

Answer (score 1):

`COMMIT PREPARED` does only two things that can potentially take a long time:

- write a commit record to WAL and sync WAL to disk
- if synchronous replication is used, wait for the OK from the synchronous standby server(s)

Since you say that your disk is not overloaded, the first reason can be ruled out.

Comment: It seens that's my disk which sometimes, during very short periods, has low I/O rates (Amazon EBS shared volumes).
I will check that

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question : slow COMMITs were related to disks running out of IOPS at some times.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).